# history.push appending query params in react js

Tags: parameters, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, query-string

I have 3 button's in my UI

1. discount
2. high
3. low

when I click the discount button I need my URL ROUTE to be changed as follows.

/products?website=ajio&category=jackets-coats&sort=discount

also, my website and category query params are dynamic soo for that I am using

**history.location.search**

and I am passing it likewise

**history.push(`/products${history.location.search}&sort=${sortWith}`)**

but when I click any other button again for sorting from the above 3 buttons it appends the last param

**products?website=ajio&category=jeans&sort=discount&sort=discount&sort=rating&sort=discount**

how can I prevent it, I just need to replace the sort name instead it is appending the whole query param